# How to place multiple widgets using grid geometry manager

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a window where the user can set the settings. I am having troubles arranging the widgets on the window. Here is what I get:

[image]

I would like the settings on the right column to appear more shifted to the left. The last setting ("Default Directory for Report") should then span over more columns if needed, but without pushing the rows above to the right.

Here is a piece of my code:

```
self.parser = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser()
self.parser.read('ALSV-Settings.ini')

''' Coarse X Scan'''
coarseXFrame = LabelFrame(self, text="Coarse X", font = ('Tahoma', 11), fg = '#3A98E4')
coarseXFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 1, sticky = W)
self.minCoarseXLabel = Label(coarseXFrame, text = 'Minimum Coarse X [um]: ', font = ('Tahoma', 10)).grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = E)
self.minCoarseXValue = Entry(coarseXFrame, bd = 5)
self.minCoarseXValue.insert(0, self.parser.get('Coarse X Scan', 'minCoarseX'))
self.minCoarseXValue.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 1, pady = 1, sticky = W)

self.maxCoarseXLabel = Label(coarseXFrame, text = 'Maximum Coarse X [um]: ', font = ('Tahoma', 10)).grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = E)
self.maxCoarseXValue = Entry(coarseXFrame, bd = 5)
self.maxCoarseXValue.insert(0, self.parser.get('Coarse X Scan', 'maxCoarseX'))
self.maxCoarseXValue.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 1, pady = 1, sticky = W)

self.stepCoarseXLabel = Label(coarseXFrame, text = 'Step Coarse X [um]: ', font = ('Tahoma', 10)).grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = E)
self.stepCoarseXValue = Entry(coarseXFrame, bd = 5)
self.stepCoarseXValue.insert(0, self.parser.get('Coarse X Scan', 'stepCoarseX'))
self.stepCoarseXValue.grid(row = 3, column = 1, padx = 1, pady = 1, sticky = W)


'''Coarse Z Scan'''
coarseZFrame = LabelFrame(self, text="Coarse Z", font = ('Tahoma', 11), fg = '#3A98E4')
coarseZFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 1, sticky = W)

self.minCoarseZLabel = Label(coarseZFrame, text = 'Minimum Coarse Z [um]: ', font = ('Tahoma', 10)).grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky = E)
self.minCoarseZValue = Entry(coarseZFrame, bd = 5)
self.minCoarseZValue.insert(0, self.parser.get('Coarse Z Scan', 'minCoarseZ'))
self.minCoarseZValue.grid(row = 1, column = 3, padx = 1, pady = 1, sticky = W)

self.maxCoarseZLabel = Label(coarseZFrame, text = 'Maximum Coarse Z [um]: ', font = ('Tahoma', 10)).grid(row = 2, column = 2, sticky = E)
self.maxCoarseZValue = Entry(coarseZFrame, bd = 5)
self.maxCoarseZValue.insert(0, self.parser.get('Coarse Z Scan', 'maxCoarseZ'))
self.maxCoarseZValue.grid(row = 2, column = 3, padx = 1, pady = 1, sticky = W)

self.stepCoarseZLabel = Label(coarseZFrame, text = 'Step Coarse Z [um]: ', font = ('Tahoma', 10)).grid(row = 3, column = 2, sticky = E)
self.stepCoarseZValue = Entry(coarseZFrame, bd = 5)
self.stepCoarseZValue.insert(0, self.parser.get('Coarse Z Scan', 'stepCoarseZ'))
self.stepCoarseZValue.grid(row = 3, column = 3, padx = 1, pady = 1, sticky = W)


'''Fine Z Scan'''
fineZFrame = LabelFrame(self, text="Fine Z", font = ('Tahoma', 11), fg = '#3A98E4')
fineZFrame.grid(row = 5, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 1, sticky = W)
self.fineStepXLabel = Label(fineZFrame, text = 'Fine step X [um]: ', font = ('Tahoma', 10)).grid(row = 6, column = 0, sticky = E)
self.fineStepXValue = Entry(fineZFrame, bd = 5)
self.fineStepXValue.insert(0, self.parser.get('Fine Z', 'stepFineX'))
self.fineStepXValue.grid(row = 6, column = 1, padx = 1, pady = 1, sticky = W)

self.minRelZLabel = Label(fineZFrame, text = 'Minimum relative Z [um]: ', font = ('Tahoma', 10)).grid(row = 7, column = 0, sticky = E)
self.minRelZValue = Entry(fineZFrame, bd = 5)
self.minRelZValue.insert(0, self.parser.get('Fine Z', 'minRelZ'))
self.minRelZValue.grid(row = 7, column = 1, padx = 1, pady = 1, sticky = W)

self.maxRelZLabel = Label(fineZFrame, text = 'Maximum relative Z [um]: ', font = ('Tahoma', 10)).grid(row = 8, column = 0, sticky = E)
self.maxRelZValue = Entry(fineZFrame, bd = 5)
self.maxRelZValue.insert(0, self.parser.get('Fine Z', 'maxRelZ'))
self.maxRelZValue.grid(row = 8, column = 1, padx = 1, pady = 1, sticky = W)

self.stepFineZLabel = Label(fineZFrame, text = 'Step Fine Z [um]: ', font = ('Tahoma', 10)).grid(row = 9, column = 0, sticky = E)
self.stepFineZValue = Entry(fineZFrame, bd = 5)
self.stepFineZValue.insert(0, self.parser.get('Fine Z', 'stepFineZ'))
self.stepFineZValue.grid(row = 9, column = 1, padx = 1, pady = 1, sticky = W)

'''Narrowed-down coarse/fine X'''
narrowedCoarseFineXFrame = LabelFrame(self, text="Narrowed-down coarse/fine X range", font = ('Tahoma', 11), fg = '#3A98E4')
narrowedCoarseFineXFrame.grid(row = 5, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 1, sticky = W)

self.minRelXLabel = Label(narrowedCoarseFineXFrame, text = 'Minimum relative X [um]: ', font = ('Tahoma', 10)).grid(row = 6, column = 2, sticky = E)
self.minRelXValue = Entry(narrowedCoarseFineXFrame, bd = 5)
self.minRelXValue.insert(0, self.parser.get('Narrowed Coarse X', 'minRelX'))
self.minRelXValue.grid(row = 6, column = 3, padx = 1, pady = 1, sticky = W)

self.maxRelXLabel = Label(narrowedCoarseFineXFrame, text = 'Maximum relative X [um]: ', font = ('Tahoma', 10)).grid(row = 7, column = 2, sticky = E)
self.maxRelXValue = Entry(narrowedCoarseFineXFrame, bd = 5)
self.maxRelXValue.insert(0, self.parser.get('Narrowed Coarse X', 'maxRelX'))
self.maxRelXValue .grid(row = 7, column = 3, padx = 1, pady = 1, sticky = W)

self.stepXCoarseZLabel = Label(narrowedCoarseFineXFrame, text = ' Step X coarse Z [um]: ', font = ('Tahoma', 10)).grid(row = 8, column = 2, sticky = E)
self.stepXCoarseZValue = Entry(narrowedCoarseFineXFrame, bd = 5)
self.stepXCoarseZValue.insert(0, self.parser.get('Narrowed Coarse X', 'stepXCoarseZ'))
self.stepXCoarseZValue .grid(row = 8, column = 3, padx = 1, pady = 1, sticky = W)

'''Settle Time'''
settleTimeFrame = LabelFrame(self, text="Settle time for stage position", font = ('Tahoma', 11), fg = '#3A98E4')
settleTimeFrame.grid(row = 9, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 1, sticky = W)

self.smallStepLabel = Label(settleTimeFrame, text = 'Settle time small step [sec]: ', font = ('Tahoma', 10)).grid(row = 10, column = 0, sticky = E)
self.smallStepValue = Entry(settleTimeFrame, bd = 5)
self.smallStepValue.insert(0, self.parser.get('Settle Time', 'settleTime_smallStep'))
self.smallStepValue .grid(row = 10, column = 1, padx = 1, pady = 1, sticky = W)

self.largeStepLabel = Label(settleTimeFrame, text = 'Settle time large step [sec]: ', font = ('Tahoma', 10)).grid(row = 11, column = 0, sticky = E)
self.largeStepValue = Entry(settleTimeFrame, bd = 5)
self.largeStepValue.insert(0, self.parser.get('Settle Time', 'settleTime_largeStep'))
self.largeStepValue .grid(row = 11, column = 1, padx = 1, pady = 1, sticky = W)

'''Default X/Z positions'''
DefaultPositionsFrame = LabelFrame(self, text="Default X/Z Positions", font = ('Tahoma', 11), fg = '#3A98E4')
DefaultPositionsFrame.grid(row = 9, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 1, sticky = W)

self.defaultXLabel = Label(DefaultPositionsFrame, text = 'Default X Position [um]: ', font = ('Tahoma', 10)).grid(row = 10, column = 2, sticky = E)
self.defaultXValue = Entry(DefaultPositionsFrame, bd = 5)
self.defaultXValue.insert(0, self.parser.get('Init Values', 'initposx'))
self.defaultXValue.grid(row = 10, column = 3, padx = 1, pady = 1, sticky = W)

self.defaultZLabel = Label(DefaultPositionsFrame, text = 'Default Z Position [um]: ', font = ('Tahoma', 10)).grid(row = 11, column = 2, sticky = E)
self.defaultZValue = Entry(DefaultPositionsFrame, bd = 5)
self.defaultZValue.insert(0, self.parser.get('Init Values', 'initposz'))
self.defaultZValue.grid(row = 11, column = 3, padx = 1, pady = 1, sticky = W)

'''Default directory for saving Report'''
DefaultPositionsFrame = LabelFrame(self, text="Default directory for Report", font = ('Tahoma', 11), fg = '#3A98E4')
DefaultPositionsFrame.grid(row = 12, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 1, sticky = W)

self.defaultRepDirLabel = Label(DefaultPositionsFrame, text = 'Default directory for Report: ', font = ('Tahoma', 10))
self.defaultRepDirLabel.grid(row = 13, column = 0, sticky = W)
self.defaultRepDir = Entry(DefaultPositionsFrame, bd = 5, width = 65)
self.savedir = self.parser.get('Report Directory', 'reportDir')
self.defaultRepDir.insert(0, self.savedir)
self.defaultRepDir.grid(row = 13, column = 1, padx = 1, pady = 1, sticky = W)
self.commandButton = Button(DefaultPositionsFrame, text = 'Select Report Directory', command = self.chooseDir, bd = 2)
self.commandButton.grid(row = 13, column = 2, padx = 1, pady = 1, sticky = W)


UpdateButton = Button(self, text = "Apply Settings", command = self.saveValues, font = ('Tahoma', 10))        
UpdateButton.grid(row = 16, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)        

cancelButton = Button(self, text = 'Exit', command = self.destroy, font = ('Tahoma', 10))
cancelButton.grid(row = 16, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Use `colspan` for `Default Directory for Report`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you grid `DefaultPositionsFrame` add in `columnspan=2` to make it stretch 2 columns. This might stuff up your other widgets but it shouldn't be to hard to reorganise them.

Comment: Thanks, that helps! However in the specific case I had to add `columnspan=3` in order to cover all the columns used by the other widgets.

Comment: @toti08 Cool! Glad it helped!